# SQL exec 'rounds?' float value

Tags: sql, dynamic, exec, rounding

Pretty sure the answer is on the ground, but i can't see it.. Code:

```
DECLARE @f float = 894589.4;
SELECT @f;
EXEC ('SELECT '+@f)
```

> **894589.4**
>   **894589**

Why? More than that if:

```
DECLARE @f float = 1.4;
```

> **1.4 1.4**

But what really makes me confuse is - this one

```
 DECLARE @f float = 1234567.4;
```

> 1234567.4 1234570

Comment: first of all, it's a `FLOAT`, so no point on you expecting an exact value out of it. Furthermore, you are concatenating it with a string without explicitely converting it, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `implicit casting` from `float` to `varchar` when building the string for `dynamic sql`.

Use [STR()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function:

```
declare @f float=894589.4
declare @sql varchar(100)='select ' + str(@f,10,2)
exec (@sql)
```

*Output:*

```
894589.4
```

Comment: Hi Farthg I think your function is "Printing" the result not EXEC

Comment: Hi @ValentinPetkov, the function is not for me, it's for Microsoft and is a built-in function for sql-server, you can get all info about it in the provided link in answer.

Comment: ypu are using EXEC as PRINT  ==> SELECT @sql ; will do same why EXEC I think the correct way to use EXEC is to submit as parameter

Comment: for that case we can use both `exec` and `sp_executesql`, but there are some differences and points [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/18/exec-vs-sp-executesql.aspx) describes them well

Comment: this one is good as well https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql

Comment: what about DECLARE @f float = 894589.44567;  4 digits after the point you will change your SP on fly by finding the numbers after the points and  and tweak the + str(@f,10,2) --> + str(@f,10,4)  ?  By the way the answer from your code have 0 in the end 894589.40  it is not 894589.4

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @f float = 894589.4;
declare @query nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @f;
set @query= 'SELECT @f' 


EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@f float', @f
```

Regardless that my answer was Downgraded by someone I think is the correct way to use EXEC to submit as parameters

what about 
     DECLARE @f float = 894589.44567;

we will change our SP  can handle the float to 4 digits  + str(@f,10,4)?

to answer more :Because is casting to INT

Comment: How does this answer the question? It provides some code that works around the problem, but does not explain what the problem the OP had was, or how the code you have posted is a better alternative. Code only answers are rarely useful.

Comment: It is the correct way to use EXEC it is answer the question. And submit as parameter

Comment: Because is casting to INT